# Как можно сделать табы

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

Скажите как можно сделать табы

Comment: [Поиск `табы [css]`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%8B+%5Bcss%5D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Tabs</h2>
<p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

[How To Create Tabs](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp)

Comment: Это кстати решение так себе... лишний раз требует записывать id каждого элемента...

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME Здравствуйте а как правильно можно написать ?

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/976913/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-hamburger-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%8B

Answer (score 0):

Можно заменить табуляции на что-нибудь, используя управляющий символ \t

```
const text="Hello,  world"
alert(text.replace("\t","1"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее, для визуального выделения, вместо единицы можно использовать <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>255</kbd>, позволяет выделить пустое пространство. Подробнее написано [тут](https://botcrawl.com/invisible-character-alt-codes-non-breaking-spaces/). Или заменить на тег, который далее выделять средствами css...