# Объясните как можно преобразовать hamburger в табы

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

```js
   var button = document.querySelector('button');
   var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
   
   button.addEventListener('click', function(){
      ul.classList.toggle('dn');
   })
```

```css
nav{
 position: relative;
 width: 400px;
 margin: auto;
}
ul{
 margin-top: 50px;
 display: flex;
 -ms-align-items: center;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 list-style-type: none;
}
button{
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 /*top: -50px;*/
} 
li{
 margin-left: 30px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.dn{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>ссылка1</li> 
    <li>ссылка2</li> 
    <li>ссылка3</li> 
    <li>ссылка4</li> 
  </ul>
   <button><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></button>
</nav>
```

Сделал hamburger 
Объясните как можно сделать теперь табы ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну идея всех табов обычно в том, чтобы при клике сперва скрыть вообще всё что открыто, после чего открыть только один нужный.

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button');
var ul = document.querySelector('ul');

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
  ul.classList.toggle('dn');
})

//var заменяют на const там, где переменная больше нигде не будет меняться
//В данном случае это выпендреж, а не необходимость.
const link = document.querySelectorAll('.link');
const tab  = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
//Запускаем цикл, который кругами будет добавлять событие "клик" на все ссылки
for(let i = 0; i < link.length; i++){
  link[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    //после клика еще раз перебираем все ссылки и используем тот момент, 
    //что ссылок и табов одинаковое количество. Поэтому одним циклом можно 
    //убрать и активный класс, и скрыть все открытые табы
    for(let u = 0; u < link.length; u++){
      link[u].classList.remove('active');
      tab[u].style.display = "none";
    }    
    //после чего на текущего кликнутого this добавляем активный класс
    this.classList.add('active');
    //И используем момент, что индекс таба, который нужно открыть, совпадает
    //с текущим кликнутым [i] из первого цикла
    tab[i].style.display = "block";
  });
}
```

```css
nav{
 position: relative;
 width: 400px;
 margin: auto;
}
ul{
 margin-top: 50px;
 display: flex;
 -ms-align-items: center;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 list-style-type: none;
}
button{
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 /*top: -50px;*/
} 
li{
 margin-left: 30px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.dn{
 display: none;
}

.active {color: red; border-bottom: 1px solid #045acf}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="link">ссылка1</li> 
    <li class="link">ссылка2</li> 
    <li class="link">ссылка3</li> 
    <li class="link">ссылка4</li> 
  </ul>
   <button><i class="fas fa-bars">i</i></button>
</nav>

<div class="tab dn">контент - 1111</div>
<div class="tab dn">контент - 2222</div>
<div class="tab dn">контент - 3333</div>
<div class="tab dn">контент - 4444</div>
```

Comment: можно мне самому написать, а потом Вам показать ?

Comment: О_о ну... ага. Если речь идет про табы W3Schools ... они не неправильные, просто добавляют чуть больше заморочек с onclick и id...

Comment: О_о вы настоящий OPTIMUS PRIME, а не десептикон

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста https://jsfiddle.net/ghvxk3sr/27/

Comment: у меня где-то ошибка

Comment: @Leks  вот проще ? https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/JVQKQK

Comment: @MaximLensky ок спасибо

Comment: @Leks только будет косяк там

Comment: @MaximLensky какой ?

Comment: @Leks  hash т.е # будет оставаться в адресной строке

Comment: @MaximLensky ясно, спасибо

Comment: @Leks ошибка бы сразу нашлась, если бы всё писалось в рамках готовой функции (function(){ вот здесь })(); — этот редактор красит в синий цвет названия объявленных переменных. https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/0noa2jz6/ - подправил вашу ссылку... там куча ошибок именно невнимательности. Если неудобно открывать консоль, можно здесь редактировать код - https://playcode.io/ , справа показывает если есть ошибка.

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME столько ошибок :(((

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME хочу еще написать табы, проверите еще раз ?